# Amazon Cloudfront and Password Protected Website

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, password-protection

I have a development/staging site which serves all it's images through Amazon Cloudfront and S3.

I am in need of password protecting the website now. Going through cPanel i can successfully do so, but now all my images are coming up blank (401 unauthorised response) on the site as they too require the same password credentials.

How can i get around the issue of serving images through amazon and password protecting the site?

As an alternative i also tried blocking access by IP rather than a password but that gives me the same outcome with a 403 (forbidden) server response on all images

Comment: Try configuring Cloudfront to [forward all request headers to the origin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html).  This should allow the `Authorization:` header to come through, letting the username and password function as expected.  Wait for your distribution status to switch from "In Progress" back to "Deployed" in the console before testing, and let us know if that does the trick.  This also disables caching, which you probably need, to prevent caching of the 401 response, and unauthorized access to cached objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working with a combination of Michael's suggestion of forwarding all request headers to the origin within amazon aws and declaring the cloudfront environment in my htaccess. Both of these together now work

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^Amazon Cloudfront$ cdn

AuthName "xxxx"
AuthUserFile "/home/xxxxxxx/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=cdn
Satisfy Any
```